# Enable runtime array bounds checks and symbols with f2py

Tags: python, debugging, fortran, f2py

I have a Fortran code that I compile to a Python extension with f2py and Intel Fortran + Visual Studio. The code has a complete testing suite and five years of history. However, lately I've been using it on new machines and the extension has been crashing Python. Whether the crash will occurs depends on things like import order and print statements in Python so I suspect some sort of memory or stack issue.

If I were working purely in a compiled language, I generally get an informative enough trace if I compile with full optimizations but building symbols; and enable runtime array bounds checks.

Is this combo possible in f2py? How do I do it?

My directory structure looks like this:

```
.
+-- setup.py
+-- lib
|   + hcclib.lib
|   + hcc.pyf
|   + hcc.for
+-- pyhcc
|   + __init__.py
|   + pyhcc.py
```

And my setup.py looks like this:

```
from numpy.distutils.core import setup
from numpy.distutils.core import Extension

ext = Extension(name = '_hcc',
             sources = ['lib/hcc.pyf', 'lib/hcc.for'],
             extra_f77_compile_args=\
             ['/check:bounds','/Z7','/O2','/nopdbfile'],
             extra_compile_args=["/Z7"])

setup(name='PyHCC',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Bindings for HCC',
      author='Me',
      author_email='me@domain.com',
      packages=['pyhcc'],
      package_dir = {'pyhcc':'pyhcc'},
      package_data={'pyhcc':['*.pyd','*.dll']},
      py_modules = ['pyhcc.__init__','pyhcc.py'],
      exclude_package_data = {'': ['*.pyc','*.pyo']},
      ext_modules = [ext]
     )
```

The interface is provided by pyhcc.py, which does argument checking and calls the extension functions in _hcc.

When I compile the extension, the fortran compiler (ifort) is evoked for the fortran and the c++ compiler (cl) is invoked for the c++. I added extra_compile_args (as suggested by Pierre) but found that I need to pass the flag in question to both C++ and Fortran so used extra_compile_args for C and extra_f77_compile_args or extra_f90_compile_args for Fortran (it treated .for as f77). Based on messages during the f2py part of the build, the flags appear to be used.

When the crash occurs, I get no message on the command line. I get message box with an offer to debug in visual studio, but when I say yes the debugger says no symbols. I don't know if this is true. Is there a way to verify whether symbols are present in the static lib hcc.lib or the output pyd file? How else should I approach this? The crash itself seems to be a segfault. I can catch it and identify the routine with a faulthandler in python, but this doesn't narrow it enough.

Comment: What build tools are you using? (setup.py, cmake, plain makefile)?

Comment: The build is in two parts. The first step builds a thrid party static library. It uses a batch file that was generated by a tool called dmake. It basically amounts to a lot of calls to the ifort compiler, so adding a flag to that would be easy. The second step is f2py, for which I'm pretty flexible.

Comment: I recommend to write a setup.py file to build the extension, see the [docs of f2py](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/f2py/distutils.html) for an example. This is based on using `numpy.distutils.core.Extension` that accepts an optional argument `extra_compile_args=None`. For gfortan, you could add `-fcheck=all` and you should be set. Let me know if this works.

Comment: This was encouraging. I am now using setup.py and I used the numpy version of Extension and it accepts extra_compile_args inside the constructor to the Extension but then it seems to route them to the C++ compiler rather than my fortran compiler. Come to think of it, for f2py there would seem to be a use for both extra C++ and extra Fortran arguments.

Comment: Using `numpy.distutils.core.Extension` files ending in `.f`, `.f90`, `.f95` and a few others should use the Fortran compiler. It would be helpful to have the structure of your source tree and the arguments to `numpy.distutils.core.Extension`.

Comment: @pierre Thanks for helping me shape this into a more substantive question. See edit.

Comment: Looking again, I see that `Extension` has other arguments among which `extra_f77_compile_args`. I can't find it in the doc but with `help(np.distutils.core.Extension)` you can see the arguments.

Comment: I just updated yet again. I think the flags are now in.

Comment: Is it fixed then? If so, I can post an actual answer.